# Hacer reload después de un cambio en base datos

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día: Si tengo esta funcion en un archivo llamado general.php:

```
$orders_status_query = tep_db_query("UPDATE " . TABLE_ORDERS . " 
SET orders_status = '34', last_modified = NOW() WHERE orders_status = '33' AND 
orders_id IN (SELECT orders_id FROM " . TABLE_GANTS . " WHERE end >= NOW() AND 
title = 'Activar Servicio')");
```

Cuando se ejecute el update, como puedo hacer para que la pagina `index.php`, realice un reload, siempre y cuando pertenezca al usuario que se realizo el update es decir con un:
 `where = order.customers_id = login.customers_id`

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes pensado hacerlo? Vas a llamar desde `index.php` a `general.php` vía AJAX? Tal vez `general.php` es un script incluído dentro de `index.php` ??

Hay muchas maneras de hacer eso que planteas, tienes que concretar un poco más para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: no tengo idea de como hacerlo puede ser con un ajax e incluir el  script dentro de index.php que cuando el detecte un cambio ejecute el reload, pero no se como hacerlo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL no soporta suscripción a actualizaciones, por lo que si no es mediante [polling](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling) no podrás conseguir lo que deseas.

Existen herramientas para analizar el log binario de transacciones como [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog-row-events.html) que te permiten obtener las actualizaciones en tablas, pero al final necesitarías un intermediario que ante un evento de actualización de datos comunique al usuario ese cambio.

Lo más eficiente es usar bases de datos que soporten ese tipo de suscripciones (como [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/)) o bien usar un middleware orientado a mensajes como RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, ZeroMQ, Amazon Simple Queue Service, MQTT, StormMQ, y un largo etcétera.

Todas estas soluciones suelen funcionar estableciendo conexiones de larga duración (mediante websockets o [long polling](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tecnolog%C3%ADa_Push#Long_polling)).

Se puede implementar mediante PHP usando long polling, pero no es escalable porque te congestionaría rápidamente el número de procesos PHP que soporta tu servidor en cuanto tuvieras muchos usuarios conectados simultáneamente, por lo que al final, sin hacer uso de un middleware orientado a mensajes, la mejor solución es implementarlo mediante polling, consultando mediante una petición XHR (usando librerías como AJAX o jQuery) de manera frecuente el estado del registro en la base de datos.

---

**Ejemplo de polling:**

Imagina que tienes un PHP que devuelve el texto "REFRESCAR" en caso de necesidad de refresco y cualquier otra cosa en caso de no necesitarlo.

Para implementar la consulta frecuente (cada 10 segundos en este ejemplo) puedes hacer:

```
setInterval("comprobar_refresco()", 10000);
```

Eso sólo deberías meterlo en el HTML del `index.php` del usuario que está esperando que se actualice algo (por ejemplo, que se active algún menú). En caso de estar activado y no necesitar esperar a ser actualizado no será necesario generar llamadas XHR, todo depende de si tiene que seguir haciendo comprobaciones o no.

La función `comprobar_refresco` será la encargada de realizar la conexión XMR al PHP para comprobar si es necesario o no refrescar la página. Un ejemplo de implementación podría ser:

```
function comprobar_refresco() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'comprobar_refresco.php'
  }).success(function(resultado) {
    if (resultado.indexOf('REFRESCAR') > -1) {
      location.reload();
    }
  });
}
```

El contenido del PHP `comprobar_refresco.php` podría ser:

```
session_start();
/* Hacer aquí las comprobaciones oportunas en la base de datos
 para saber si el usuario necesita refresco o no */
if ($necesita_refresco === true) {
  die('REFRESCAR');
} else {
  die('NO');
}
```

Un ejemplo de comprobación podría ser:

```
/* $_SESSION['orders_status'] contiene el antiguo valor del
registro orders_status del usuario y $fila contiene el resultado
de la consulta SQL actual */
$necesita_refresco = ($_SESSION['orders_status'] != $fila['orders_status']);
$_SESSION['orders_status'] = $fila['orders_status'];
```

Con esto enviamos un refresco cuando el valor de `orders_status` cambie de valor.

Si no se ha definido nunca la variable de sesión `order_status` no hará nada la primera vez (`$necesita_refresco` valdrá falso), en la siguiente línea se guardará el valor inicial, aunque lo ideal sería que el `index.php` fuera quien generara dicho valor para que la primera vez que se compruebe la necesidad de reinicio parta de un valor inicial conocido.

Comment: ok fijate, la cuestion es cuando se realiza el update, un ejemplo cambio el valor de orders_status = '33' cambia a orders_status = '34' que se ejecute en index.php un reload, no se como hacerlo, es como si tubiera un reloj que le indique si hubo un cambio en orders_status ejecuta el reload para que cargue a la pagina el nuevo valor,

Comment: Te he puesto un ejemplo, espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: He agradado más código de ejemplo con los datos que me has facilitado.

Comment: vale oscar muchas gracias, un solo detalle me falta... el order_status se que el ejemplo solo puse 2 valores 33  y 34 puede ser cualquier numero, de hecho los estados de order_status va desde 1 hasta 40 si ocurre algun cambio en la base datos de cualquier numero debe realizar un reload entiendo por lo que dices en (contiene el antiguo valor del registro orders_status del usuario y $fila) puedo hacer una tabla temporal que guarde el ultimo valor de order_status a un usuario y lo compare si es igual no refresca si ha cambiado refresca y guarda este ultimo valor en la tabla temporal

Comment: Por supuesto que se puede hacer. Si lo único que quieres es controlar el cambio de valor de `orders_status` entonces el código se simplifica :) te dejo la edición en unos minutos. Por cierto, no es necesario crear una tabla temporal para almacenar el último valor del `order_status` de un usuario, para eso hago uso de la variable de sesión `$_SESSION['order_status']`.